# Why assembly code is different for simple C program with different gcc version?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm understanding the basics of assembly and c programming.

I compiled following simple program in C,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;
  int b;
  a = 10;
  b = 88

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with following command,

gcc -ggdb -fno-stack-protector test.c -o test

The disassembled code for above program with gcc version 4.4.7 is:

```
5                      push   %ebp
89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
c7 45 f8 0a 00 00 00    movl   $0xa,-0x8(%ebp)
c7 45 fc 58 00 00 00    movl   $0x58,-0x4(%ebp)
b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
c9                      leave
c3                      ret
90                      nop
```

However disassembled  code for same program with gcc version 4.3.3 is:

```
8d 4c 23 04     lea     0x4(%esp), %ecx
83 e4 f0        and     $0xfffffff0, %esp
55              push    -0x4(%ecx)
89 e5           mov     %esp,%ebp
51              push     %ecx
83 ec 10        sub      $0x10,%esp
c7 45 f4 0a 00 00 00 00 movl $0xa, -0xc(%ebp)
c7 45 f8 58 00 00 00 00 movl $0x58, -0x8(%ebp)
b8 00 00 00 00          mov $0x0, %eax
83 c4 10                add $0x10,%esp
59                      pop %ecx
5d                      pop %ebp
8d 61 fc                lea -0x4(%ecx),%esp
c3                      ret
```

Why there is difference in the assembly code?
As you can see in second assembled code, Why pushing %ecx on stack?
What is significance of `and     $0xfffffff0, %esp`?

note: OS is same

Comment: Why there *shouldn't* be a difference?

Comment: Looks like the second one is debug version

Comment: @EugeneSh., maybe the reasoning behind the question is that the same code should produce the same compiler output, so these executables are _exactly_ identical as they've been produced from exactly the same code. Okay, _the executables_ may not be the same because the libraries the object files were linked to could be different, but the assembly should be a direct translation from C to machine language, shouldn't it?

Comment: Compilers change and improve over time. So you would hope that 4.4.7 generates better code than 4.3.3.

Comment: @ForceBru yeah, but why? Compilers mission is to produce valid executable for target platform from the source code. There's absolutely nothing about being deterministic, or producing minimal / fastest / ... binary, actually if it wouldn't be impractical for the compiler developers (in case of bug hunting), the very same compiler with same command line options may produce different binary every time, why not?

Comment: @ForceBru ups... "the assembly should be a direct translation from C to machine language" - absolutely not, nothing of the requirements put on compiler comes even close to it. If you want direct instruction -> machine code translation, you should use Assembly.

Comment: Surprisingly the same gcc version generates also different code for different CPUs or even different OS. And gcc generates different code than clang or MSVC, icc, etc. Not clear what the problem is. What have you researched? Why do you ask this very basic question?

Comment: @Ped7g: How would that even be possible, considering machine language has no concept of datatypes, functions, local variables, etc.

Comment: @Olaf I you feel this question is so basic, perhaps you can answer it? Why did the compiler generate such strange code? Was GCC 4.3.3 completely broken or did it have some reason? If not, I think your superior attitude is quite unwarranted.

Comment: @Ped7g, I'm not keen on compilers much, so I might be completely wrong, but my thought was that a compiler should generate the code that does _absolutely_ the same thing as the C code is intended to do. Thus, why even try to do something in many ways if you could do it as effectively in only one way? The first assembly code seems pretty reasonable to me: you ask the computer to do this and that, and so it does, but the second one is crazy: why do all this (seemingly unnecessary) stuff?

Comment: @jforberg: We don't even know to OS and default optimisation settings of gcc (no, the command line is **not** enough). OP did not do a bit of research what a C translator has to do (i.e. abstract machine, etc). There is a lot of material to be found by a simple search already.

Comment: Well, both are clearly debug builds. So it's sort of pointless to reason about the output, as that assembly is quite raw output of base definitions of certain basic actions defined by compiler, more like showing their internal state, than being a compiled program. Those internal states may differ vastly between different versions of compiler, as the developers of compiler try to improve it. The `and ..,esp` may be some leak of 64b platform implementation, when they extended stack alignment tracing to the internal state. Or anything else. That internal state is tuned as optimizer input data.

Comment: @ForceBru: 1) The result of compilation shall have the same **observable behaviour**. Not the same "thing" as the C code. 2) Try writing a complex program in Assembler yourself and you will see there is not just 1 single way, Resp. finding that way will take a lot of time reading datasheets, instruction timing, pipeline/cache details, etc. Also optimisation is no single dimension; there are at least two: speed and space (the latter alone can have multiple dimensions: code, data/stack, etc.).

Comment: @ForceBru well, they do the same thing in C, but the C has no direct translation to machine code, there are tens to hundreds of reasonable ways how to translate C source, millions of unreasonable ones. Even if you use `-O3` telling compiler "I want fastest code", that's NP complete problem, not solvable by compiler, and the output is only heuristically close to the optimal solution. The main problem in your logic is " you could do it as effectively in only one way" - you can't. Even Assembly programmers for medium sized task would produce different code, there are too many [***llions] ways.

Comment: @ForceBru: the first code is very bad, as actually `xor eax,eax ret` will do everything that function does (assigning value to unused local variable in C is meaningless operation, and doesn't have to be executed by CPU at all).

Comment: Much of the code you are looking at it is to align the stack to a 16-byte boundary and restores the stack properly at the end. `and     $0xfffffff0, %esp` in particular is used to align the stack down to the next 16-byte aligned boundary (essentially making ESP evenly divisible by 16). Without 16-byte alignment functions (like the ones provided by `glibc`) may fail with unaligned memory access if it was built to use SSE aligned instructions. The 32-bit ABI used by a particular distros of Linux defines whether such alignment is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Compilers are not required to produce identical assembly code for the same source code. The C standard allows the compiler to optimize the code as they see fit as long as the *observable behaviour* is the same. So, different compilers may generate different assembly code.

For your code, [GCC 6.2](https://godbolt.org/g/xYpX3Y) with `-O3` generates just:

```
xor     eax, eax
ret
```

because your code essentially does nothing. So, it's reduced to a simple return statement.

Comment: While you are correct, I think the question is why the compiler would generate such code. Since OP can read assembler code, I think we can assume he also knows that compilers sometimes generate different code for the same input program. (Note: I didn't downvote you)

Comment: @jforberg "I think the question is why the compiler would generate such code" -  my answer says *because it can/is allowed*. I doubt OP knows what you claim OP knows because, if OP had that knowledge already, this question wouldn't have araised.

Comment: I think we should always give OP the benefit of the doubt, especially since answers on SO aren't just for the benefit of the OP. I personally have no idea why GCC would generate the code in the second example but I would be interested to know. No-one in this thread is even attempting to answer that question, which I think is sad. I'll stop now because I don't want to get in a fight with you twice in the same day. Good evening.

Comment: @jforberg You could answer it. It was already answered in the comments, it's probably a debug build but we aren't given enough information about how gcc was built. But it would be nice if the OP clarified the question.

Comment: @jforberg I didn't have *fight* with you or anyone. I posted exactly one comment on *that* and that too was directed at [Martijn Pieters](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) (for which he responded). If disagreeing with you is called fight then I can only say *Welcome to the internet!*.

Answer (score 0):

To give you some idea, how many ways exists to create valid code for particular task, I thought this example may help.

From time to time there are size coding competitions, obviously targetting Assembly programmers, as you can't compete with compiler against hand written assembly at this level at all.

The competition tasks are fairly trivial to make the entry level and total effort reasonable, with precise input and output specifications (down to single byte or pixel perfection).

So you have almost trivial exact task, human produced code (at the moment still outperforming compilers for trivial task), with single simple rule "minimal size" as a goal.

With your logic it's absolutely clear every competitor should produce the same result.

The real world answer to this is for example:

[Hugi Size Coding Competition Series](http://www.hugi.scene.org/compo/) - Compo29 - Random Maze Builder

12 entries, size of code (in bytes): 122, 122, 128, 135, 136, 137, 147, ... 278 (!).

And I bet the first two entries, both having 122B are probably different enough (too lazy to actually check them).

Now producing valid machine code from high level programming language and by machine (compiler) is lot more complex task. And compilers can't compete with humans in reasoning, most of the "how good code is produced by c++ compiler" stems from C++ language itself being defined quite close to machine code (easy to compile) and from brute CPU power allowing the compilers to work on thousands of variants for particular code path, searching for near-optimal solution mostly by brute force.

Still the numerical "reasoning" behind the optimizers are state of art in their own way, getting to the point where human are still unreachable, but more like in their own way, just as humans can't achieve the efficiency of compilers within reasonable effort for full-sized app compilation.

At this point reasoning about some debug code being different in few helper prologue/epilogue instructions... Even if you would find difference in optimized code, and the difference being "obvious" to human, it's still quite a feat the compiler can produce at least that, as compiler has to apply universal rules on specific code, without truly understanding the context of task.